# Using expect for passwords does not work, nothing is entered

Tags: bash, shell, expect, heredoc, su

I'm trying to use expect to enter values in a script, some of the values are passwords.

Expect does not enter the passwords, it awkwardly ends its child script and then itself.

I've broken it down to simplicity - trying to change user

```
su - some_random_user
./suscript
```

Where suscript is:

```
#!/bin/bash

expect <<- DONE
    spawn su - root
    expect -ex {assword:}
    send -- "my_password\n"
DONE
```

Does there seem to be anything wrong with this? I see no reason why it shouldn't work.

Edit - I think I figured out the problem, now I just need the solution.
the script I'm running (and the script above) both call passwd, a process that was not spawned by expect, therefore not listened to by expect.
I know exactly when passwd is going to be spawned, so I can sit in a wait loop until I see it under a process list.

The issue is - once I get a PID/process name, how do I make expect listen to it as if it spawned the process?

Comment: script runs in a subshell, logs in in a subshell, exits the subshell. command promt won't change or you won't see any password entered. What are you expecting?

Comment: `"my_password\n"` should be `"my_password\r"`

Comment: To prevent expect from exiting immediately after typing the password, add the command `interact` after sending the password. Storing root's password in a clear text file is stupid. You should investigate using `sudo` instead.

Comment: I'm not worried about that, I'm just creating a user account to install a piece of software. Interact returns "spawn id exp0 not open", however I am definitely spawning something